# How do I get rectanuglar tabs in Google Chrome on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm on Windows 10 and would like to make them rectangular (mainly to make them stop overlapping the title bar since I use custom themes). The problem is, I'm no good with scripting and can't focus very well due to an oxygen deficiency in the part of my brain that deals with focus. I found an extension on firefox that makes firefox use it's old rectangular tabs and would like it if the google chrome tabs could be made to match that shape and size. (Google Chrome is far faster than firefox on my system which is why i want this for google chrome) Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It will be very hard to do that. You can enable "Material Design" that is an developer and experimental feauture. [Chrome with Material Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxalg.jpg)

And here is a [tutorial](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/12/17/google-launches-experimental-material-design-interface-in-chrome/) to do that.

Oh. You can use Vivaldi Browser that has a triangular design.

Comment: Well, another reason I prefer Google Chrome i because the add page feature for bookmarks doesn't require me to manually type the url and name into it. It also doesn't make me drag it into any bookmarks bar folders and/or sub folders. I've yet to come across a browser that has those bookmarking abilities. However, I've gone ahead and downloaded Vivaldi, and although I like it's metro design, I notice it can't import bookmarks fro Google Chrome. If I can get those imported, and if Vivaldi has at least a decent enough bookmarks feature, than it might serve as a decent replacement.

Comment: Also please note that Google Chrome with "Material Design" is "experimental". Some things don't work or are uncompleted in Chrome "Material Design" User Interface.